# Tasker: How can I delete a file after a month

Tags: tasker

Is there a way to delete all files in a folder that are over a month old using Tasker?

Answer (score 2):

That's rather a question of shell stuff. See this example shell command:

```
find /some/dir -ignore_readdir_race -cmin -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f +1440 ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete
```

This would delete all files in `/some/dir` which are older than 1440 minutes (i.e. 24h). Just multiply the 1440 by 30 to get 1 month, and fire the command via a time-based profile.